# Frequent "display driver(windows8)" errors on windows 10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, drivers, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I also very frequently get the BSOD "video_scheduler_internal_error".
I have a ASUS ROG G-series laptop, with an nvidia 860m. I upgraded to windows 10 from windows 8 using the built-in upgrade function. 
I've tried completely uninstalling all nvidia drivers using programs and features, and uninstalling all display adapter drivers using device manager, and the reinstalling via nvidia's actual website. Neither has solved the problem.
Any suggestions?

Comment: the 860M has some issues. Try the hotfix driver: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/900924/geforce-drivers/geforce-hotfix-driver-359-12-for-geforce-860m-notebook-gpus-released-12-2-15-/

Comment: does the new driver fixes the issues?